# Pydantic ValueError: [TypeError("'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

You have a simple pydantic model with datetime attribute, like below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    dt: datetime = datetime.now
```

When you try to serialize this model to json, that try to return it from fastapi end point. You get following error.

```
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52831 - "POST /yard-manager/check_rule?id_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 94, in receive
    return self.receive_nowait()
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 89, in receive_nowait
    raise WouldBlock
anyio.WouldBlock

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 43, in call_next
    message = await recv_stream.receive()
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 114, in receive
    raise EndOfStream
anyio.EndOfStream

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 269, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 92, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 147, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 68, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
  File "c:\Users\ati_o\Projects\sms-digital\SSAB\ssab-ox-mes-pss-alg\rest_service\middleware.py", line 36, in check_header_token
    response = await call_next(request)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 46, in call_next
    raise app_exc
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 36, in coro
    await self.app(scope, request.receive, send_stream.send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 93, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 670, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 266, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 249, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 149, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 157, in jsonable_encoder
    return jsonable_encoder(
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 113, in jsonable_encoder
    encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(
  File "WINDOWS_USERNAME\scoop\apps\python310\current\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 156, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors)
ValueError: [TypeError("'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a function to your field not a value.
That is you are assigning **datetime.now** function to your field, not a current date and time value.
Therefore, pydantic cannot serialize it.
Change your default value like below to call now as function like now()

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Model(BaseModel):
    dt: datetime = datetime.now()
```

Simple, but when you do not know a framework, it could be a stopper.